# SVN Problem You're not allowed to commit the local.properties file because it contains your SVN user credentials

Tags: eclipse, svn, svn-hooks

when i try to commit the code it says :

```
Sending        .
Sending        sql/aa.sql
Transmitting file data .done
Committing transaction...
svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
You're not allowed to commit the local.properties file because it contains your SVN user credentials.
```

and im using the SVN to commit the code to respoitory svn nd also the file local.properties i added it to ignore file too
using the cmd :

```
svn propset svn:ignore 'local.properties' .
```

but nothing works , i always face this isssue and i cant commit the code perfectly into the repository and also in the repository there is no file named local.properties ,

i guess the is an conflict with the commit  or something like that
are there is a solution to remove any pre-commit in waiting and restart over ?

i tryed to clone the repository and commit again but the same thing i guess the file local.properties are stcu in some point ...

any help ?
and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "You're not allowed to commit the local.properties" is generated by a custom pre-commit hook script. The hook script was added by the repository or server administrator.

You can examine your local changes using the `svn status` command to find out if the file `local.properties` is scheduled for commit. Since you mention Eclipse, it also should have a window to examine local changes.

If you are absolutely sure that your commit does not have the file `local.properties` then you should contact the administrator for assistance. Perhaps the pre-commit hook script has a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hello , yes im sure that the local.properties is not in the list to commit , 
when enter 
svn status .
there is not local.properties in the list 
so what do u think ?

Comment: @MRInt contact the administrator for assistance. You - as a user - have no control over the pre-commit hook script.